# Error de Node: express-validator: a validator/sanitizer with name logo does not exist

Tags: nodejs, express.js

Tengo la siguiente ruta de archivos que me ayudan a tener esquemas de validación (utilizando `express-validator`):

Este es mi router:

```javascript
const express = require('express');
const { checkSchema } = require('express-validator');
const { validateFields } = require('../../../middlewares/validateFields');
const router = express.Router();

const configuracionRouter = require('./configuracion');

const { validateJwt } = require('../../../middlewares/validateJwt');
const { CurriculosController } = require('../../../controllers/plataforma');
const { commonSchemas } = require('./validation-schemas');

router.use(validateJwt);

// Rutas que tienen que ver sólo con currículos (webCurriculos / web_curriculos)
router.post(
  '/',
  checkSchema(commonSchemas.createCurriculoSchema),
  validateFields,
  CurriculosController.createCurriculo
);

module.exports = router;
```

Este es el archivo **index.js** que está en './validation-schemas':

```javascript
const commonSchemas = require('./common');

module.exports = { commonSchemas };
```

Este es mi **common.js**:

```javascript
const { createCurriculoSchema } = require('./curriculos');

module.exports = {
  createCurriculoSchema,
};
```

Este es mi **curriculos.js**:

```javascript
const { webCurriculosCategorias } = require('./../../../../database/config').sequelize.models;
const { databaseSchemas, commonSchemas } = require('../../../common/validation-schemas/');
const { idSchemaFactory } = databaseSchemas;

const createCurriculoSchema = {
  idCategoria: idSchemaFactory('idCategoria', 'body', webCurriculosCategorias),
  logo: commonSchemas.logo.asignarValores('body', false),
  nombre: commonSchemas.nombre.asignarValores('body', false),
  descripcion: commonSchemas.descripcion('body', false),
};

module.exports = { createCurriculoSchema };
```

Y este mi **commonSchemas.js**:

```javascript
const ordenSchema = {
  asignarValores(location = 'body', optional = true, min = 1, max = 100) {
    return {
      in: location,
      optional: optional,
      notEmpty: {
        errorMessage: '`orden` es requerido.',
        bail: true,
      },
      isInt: {
        errorMessage: '`orden` debe ser un entero mayor a ' + parseInt(min) - 1,
        bail: true,
        options: { min: min, max: max },
      },
    };
  },
};

const estadoSchema = {
  asignarValores: (location = 'body', optional = true, options = [0, 1, 2]) => {
    return {
      in: location,
      optional: optional,
      isIn: {
        options: [options],
        errorMessage: '`estado` debe ser 0, 1 o 2',
      },
    };
  },
};

const logo = {
  asignarValores: (location, optional = true, max = 100) => {
    return {
      in: location,
      optional: optional,
      notEmpty: {
        errorMessage: '`logo` requerido',
        bail: true,
      },
      isString: {
        errorMessage: '`logo` debe ser una cadena de texto.',
        bail: true,
      },
      isLength: {
        errorMessage: '`logo` no debe ser mayor a ' + max + ' caracteres',
        options: { max: max },
      },
    };
  },
};

const nombre = {
  asignarValores: (location, optional = true, max = 100) => {
    return {
      in: location,
      optional: optional,
      notEmpty: {
        errorMessage: '`nombre` requerido',
        bail: true,
      },
      isString: {
        errorMessage: '`nombre` debe ser una cadena de texto.',
        bail: true,
      },
      isLength: {
        errorMessage: '`nombre` no debe ser mayor a 100 caracteres',
        options: { max: max },
      },
    };
  },
};

const descripcion = (location, optional = true) => {
  return {
    in: location,
    optional: optional,
    notEmpty: {
      errorMessage: '`descripcion` requerido',
      bail: true,
    },
    isString: {
      errorMessage: '`descripcion` debe ser una cadena de texto.',
      bail: true,
    },
  };
};

module.exports = { ordenSchema, estadoSchema, logo, nombre, descripcion };
```

Y la consola me arroja el siguiente error:

> express-validator: a validator/sanitizer with name idCategoria does not exist

> express-validator: a validator/sanitizer with name logo does not exist

> express-validator: a validator/sanitizer with name nombre does not exist

> express-validator: a validator/sanitizer with name descripcion does not exist

Comment: No uses expressjs. Usa node directamente

Comment: Es que ya es un proyecto hecho. No puedo hacer muchos cambios.

Comment: Me dice que debo definir el sanitizador, pero ni idea de cómo hacerlo, si estoy utilizando objetos.